# LinkError: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' - Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gcc, arm

I'm trying to run a Python Script, and it gives me the following error:

```
http://pastebin.com/wpMvJjCc
```

My server is running "Ubuntu Trusty (14.04 LTS)".
The hosting company I'm using for my VPS is "ScaleWay.com", who claims their VPS's are ARM based.
How can I solve this issue?
Thanks!
Toby.

Comment: It says pretty clearly that it cannot find a library (spotify_embedded_shared). Are you certain you installed it?

Comment: @nneonneo Apologies, I don't know how to. The documentation for https://github.com/Fornoth/spotify-connect-web is not the best. I've just done a wget from the repository download, unzipped and installed a few dependencies. Do I need to "Make" or something?

Comment: That log isn't really long enough to require a pastebin - and it will cause this question to not show up in searches for the same error message...